# Getting status of another app from a background task

Tags: android

I am going to add a series of functionality to Android depending on the status of the mobile browser. The thing I am trying to implement is going to take different actions when the browser failed to load, loading or successfully loaded the webpage.

I don't think that there is an interface or API to do it but still wondering any possibilities. I could not find anything helpful on the internet.

Comment: I don't see a specific question here. You don't have control over the status of other apps unless they broadcast state changes. IF you have control over the other app you can use intents and pass data to a background service.

Comment: I know that it is not possible to get any data from another app unless the app itself has a way to share it intentionally, but I canoot find any information whether I could use the advantages of rooting the phone.